# Calling onCreate() from locked screen

Tags: java, android, gesture, android-sensors, sensormanager

I am developing an android emergency app and I want to add a feature that can call a certain method from my activity class when the screen is locked. Is there anyway for my app to detect any kind gestures like shake, screen tap pattern or any kind of movement when the screen is locked?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will work, but I think you can put a listener in a service and put the servicee in the foreground. I have no clue what exactly youwant to achieve but this is what I can think of right now. BTW -- [pass information from a service the foreground activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111419/pass-information-from-a-service-the-foreground-activity)

Comment: Ok to make things simpler, I have a single button app that when clicked, sends a pre-configured email programatically. What I want now is to activate the app without entering the MainActivity and pressing the button. I want to activate it using some kind of gestures when the screen is locked. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Sorry, I'm on phone and have difficulties with editing, so posting again. I believe if you get this listener off in the service and figure out how to use it (haven't used it) I think it can work. On getting the correct gestures send the e-mail.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to follow the link to see if I can come up with something.